# type universe cannot resolve assembly in Windows Phone 7.1

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1

I am facing this error when I add a dll in my Windows Phone 7.1 project

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only DLL you can reference in a Windows Phone app are the PCL (Portable Class Library) and those compiled specifically for Silverlight. The DLL you're trying to add targets the desktop version of the .NET Framework, and therefore can't be used.

Comment: Thanx KooKiz
but actually I want to send an email with attachments
so how can I send an email with attachments programmatically in windows phone 7.1

Comment: @RizwanQureshi Sending an email with an attachments isn't possible in windows phone through code, there might be some third party tools available for the same, but currently there is no support provided, as to make an attachment we need to browse all the files available and there is no such provision in wp to do that. Hence